# SQL delete rows using full join

Tags: mysql

I currently have 2 tables in my database, one called `User`, and the other `Product`, where each row in `User` stores information about a user, and each row in `Product` stores a product that one user has:

```
 User (Username, password, phone_num, address, email)
 Product (Username, item_name, type, taste, price, image)
```

User has primary key `Username`, and Product has primary keys `Username` and `item_name`, and `Username` in Product is also a foreign key that refers to `Username` in User.

I'm trying to use a join query that, when executes, deletes both a user and all the products that are related to this particular user. Right now I have two separate working queries in PHP:

```
"DELETE from User where Username='$username'";
"DELETE from Product where Username='$username'";
```

Is there a way that I can combine these two queries using join to achieve the same goal? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete rows from multiple tables at once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653837/delete-rows-from-multiple-tables-at-once)

Comment: @JNevill   Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot delete from two tables simultaneously in one command. Here is a link to the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html

What you could do is set up a cascading delete through your foreign key constraint. When you delete a User if there is a foreign key reference in the Product table that row will automatically get deleted too. You'll achieve the your objective of deleting both with a single command but you'll do it not with a join but a constraint. Here's the constraint documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html